# Set robotframework teardown keyword in middle of test case

Tags: python, robotframework

I know from googling and reading robot framework user guide, robot framework has 'teardown' option where at end of testcase or suite, it calls keyword that can be used for cleanup.

I am trying to utilize this teardown for the objects (libraries I import) in the middle of the test.

```
*** Settings ***
Test Timeout     10 minutes
Library          OperatingSystem
Library          String


*** Variables ***
${SUPER_SCRIPT_NAME}    Test

*** Test Cases ***
Dummy
    [Documentation]
    LOG    HEllo xyz blha blah
    Should Be True    4 < 8    msg=*ERROR* 4 is not greater than 8
    Import Library    ${CURDIR}/dummy.py    WITH NAME    dummy_obj
    dummy_obj.start_inside_dummy_obj    ${data_from_arg}
    Do Something Else For 4 Min
    Do Something Else For 4 Min
    dummy_obj.start_inside_secondary_obj    ${other_arg_data}
    Do Something Else For 4 Min
    dummy_obj.cleanup_everything    # inside this main_obj calls inside_dummy_obj.cleanup(), which calls inside_secondary_obj.cleanup().  Once "inside_secondary_obj" cleanup() is complete inside_dummy_obj.cleanup() is completed, which completes dummy_obj's cleanup_everything()
```

Here is the problem I have: I import and create an object of python library (lets call it "dummy_obj"), that imports and creates object inside (lets call this "inside_dummy_obj"), and this imports and creates a object inside it (lets call this "inside_secondary_obj").  In a normal case where the test completes successfully, I call the imported library/object keyword for cleanup where the the "main_obj", calls "inside_main_obj"'s cleanup, which calls the "inside_secondary_obj" 's cleanup; the cleanup of all of them occurs in order gracefully.

I need to be able to call "dummy_obj.cleanup_everything" keyword during the "Do Something Else For 4 Min" keyword if an abort (Cntrl-C) were to be issued.

I don't know if the Teardown keyword can be set dynamically as it is not required to be set before the dummy_obj object is created.  I tried experimenting with all the python **del**() objects but it doesn't seem to delete them in order.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose I misinterpreted the testcase teardown.  Just did this and seems to be working:

```
*** Settings ***
Test Timeout     10 minutes
Library          OperatingSystem
Library          String


*** Variables ***
${SUPER_SCRIPT_NAME}    Test

*** Test Cases ***
Dummy
    [Documentation]
    LOG    HEllo xyz blha blah
    Should Be True    4 < 8    msg=*ERROR* 4 is not greater than 8
    Import Library    ${CURDIR}/dummy.py    WITH NAME    dummy_obj
    dummy_obj.start_inside_dummy_obj    ${data_from_arg}
    Do Something Else For 4 Min
    Do Something Else For 4 Min
    dummy_obj.start_inside_secondary_obj    ${other_arg_data}
    Do Something Else For 4 Min
    dummy_obj.cleanup_everything    # inside this main_obj calls inside_dummy_obj.cleanup(), which calls inside_secondary_obj.cleanup().  Once "inside_secondary_obj" cleanup() is complete inside_dummy_obj.cleanup() is completed, which completes dummy_obj's cleanup_everything()
    [Teardown]    dummy_obj.cleanup
```